# ¿Los hostings compartidos como Don Web tienen algún tipo de caché de usuarios para aplicaciones con Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Tengo una aplicación hecha con **laravel** corriendo en un servidor compartido (Don Web) el cual manifiesta un comportamiento extraño.

Si voy a las tablas de la base de datos que está en el `.env` encuentro la tabla user. Entiendo que ahí están los usuarios pero solo hay dos: test y admín. Parecen usuarios creados con el procedimiento de "seed" pero cuando intento logearme no toma esos usuarios y si otros que no sé donde están.

Si cambio algo en el `.env`, lo renombro, renombro todas las tablas de la base para provocar un error no cambia nada, no se ven reflejado los cambios.

Mi duda es ¿dónde está buscando esos usuarios? No sé si hay un caché en algún pero no creo que el procedimiento de login consulte primero cachés antes de ir a buscar los usuarios en la base `mysql` ¿o sí?

El punto es que como está en un hosting compartido no puedo ejecutar comandos.

También me encuentro con que si lleno otras tablas no aparecen en los combobox.

Es un software de toma de inventario que alguien hizo y manifiestan que funcionó en su momento.

¿A alguien se le ocurre por donde puede venir el problema?

En el composer.json tengo esto:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^3.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "tcg/voyager": "^1.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Y en el packet.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14"
    }
}
```

Agradezco cualquier observación. Es la primera vez que toco un proyecto de estas características.

Este es el modelo de User que está en la carpeta appp/Models

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends \TCG\Voyager\Models\User
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

[image: Carpetas del proyecto]

No veo controladores especificos para el login
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Contenido del archivo Controller.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

Comment: Muestranos la logica del login (probablemente en un controlador), y si ahi usa un modelo eloquent (como User), tambien el modelo.

Comment: Gracias. Ahí agregué algo más de información.

Comment: Ah, ok. Veo que tu modelo User extiende de `\TCG\Voyager\Models\User`. Nunca usè voyager como para tirarte alguna pista. Le estoy dando una mirada rapida a la [documentacion](https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/getting-started/configurations) y veo que tiene un archivo de configuracion. Tambien este [issue](https://github.com/thedevdojo/voyager/issues/2266) que al parecer dice que por defecto usa la tabla `users`. No se si te sirva, pero investigarìa un poco mas por ahi

Comment: Para limpiar la cache sin la linea de comandos podes probar lo que dice [acà](https://visioncodigo.com/blog/como-borrar-cache-manualmente-en-laravel) o directamente eliminar el contenido del directorio `bootstrap/cache` (menos el .gitignore)